# runjags summaries in Linux

Tags: linux, class, plot, runjags

I set `summarise = TRUE` in the function `run.jags`, then saved the output object as `save(out, file="out.RData")`.

When I later load this object I can retrieve the summaries, plots, etc.

However, when I use the exact same code and run the model, and save output on a Linux cluster, then later load the object in Windows to work with it, the summaries and plots are not available. When I type `summary(out)`, `print(out)`, `plot(out)`, or `add.summaries(out)`, I get the following error message:

> Error: Invalid runjags.object provided; the output of a runjags function (with class 'runjags') must be supplied

This even though `class(out)` returns `"runjags"`.

In fact, `names(out)` reveals that the summaries (and a lot of other stuff) is not included in the output. The help file does indicate that summaries/plots, etc, are included by default.

Is there something about running the model in Linux that 1) prevents summaries from being generated, or 2) messes up the class of the output object?

I can of course use the coda package and do `out2 <- as.mcmc.list(out)`, then I can use coda function to work with the output.

Comment: The summaries that are produced are not platform dependent, so it is not a specific issue of moving from one platform to another.  My best guess is that the versions of runjags differ (perhaps between 1.x and 2.x) - producing results using 1.x and then loading them in 2.x should be supported, but going the other way will cause issues like you are seeing.  Can you confirm version numbers on the two systems? Note that 2.0.2 was uploaded to CRAN at the weekend.

Comment: You are correct. I had 1.x on the remote Linux machine, and 2.x on my local Windows machine. I could read the object going either way, but the object created in 1.x somehow was not recognized as class `"runjags"` in 2.x. But, in any case, updating `runjags` solved the problem - I should have thought of that! Many thanks.

Comment: No worries.  Glad it wasn't anything more serious :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was not Linux (see comment by Matt Denwood), but an old version of `runjags`. I updated `runjags` on the Linux machine (well, I had the system admin do it), and that fixed the problem.